# C# Call repeater onload event

Tags: c#, repeater, nested-repeater

How to call a function just after repeater loaded with data.

**Design:-**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptParent" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptParent_OnItemBound">
    <ItemTemplate>        
          <asp:Repeater ID="rptChild" runat="server" OnLoad="rptChild_OnLoad">
              <ItemTemplate> 
              </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:Repeater>   
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**C# Code:-**

```
     protected void rptChild_OnLoad(object sender, System.EventHandler e)
     {
        // code...
     }
```

I have also tried below code :-

```
 protected void rptChild_OnLoad(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
 {
 }
```

But getting an error :- No overload for 'rptChild_OnLoad' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method needs to be an [Event Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx).

That means, it **must** have the following signature:

```
protected void rptChild_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
```